# asyncio: приостановка когда список пуст/возобновление работы корутины/задачи когда не пуст

Tags: python, python-3.5, asyncio

Нужно, чтобы работа корутины/задачи приостанавливалась, когда список ws_list пуст, и возобновлялась, если есть хотя бы один элемент в списке:

```
import asyncio

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(coro())
    loop.run_until_complete(task)

async def coro():
    i = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        i += 1
        print(i)

ws_list = []
main()
```

1. Приостанавливать/возобновлять нужно корутину или задачу? Хотя в данном случае это для меня не принципиально, но хотелось бы, чтоб было понимание.
2. Добрые люди в инете посоветовали использовать asyncio.Condition, но, почитав офдоки и перерыв гугл, так и не понял, как его применить.
3. Какие еще способы можно использовать, помимо asyncio.Condition?
4. Почему при запуске этого кода в линукс (python 3.5), мне не обязательно печатать строчку loop.run_until_complete(task), задача запускается и без нее, а в виндовс (python 3.6) эта строчка обязательна? Это связано с версией питона или с ОС?
5. Как грамотно принудительно остановить loop вместе с таской?

Comment: В линуксе тоже обязательно дожидаться конца таска. разные вопросы лучше задать в разных вопросах чтоб получить отдельные ответы.

Comment: loop останавливать нельзя в asincio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import asyncio
import signal

ws_list = []

def shutdown():
    # Отменяем все задачи
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()


async def consumer(condition):
    while True:
        try:
            with await condition:  # Захватываем condition
                await condition.wait()  # Ждём condition
                print(ws_list[-1])
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            break  # Задача отменена, выходим из цикла


async def producer(condition):
    # Даём возможность consumer'е запуститься
    # раньше, чтобы он не пропустил первое число
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    i = 0
    while True:
        # Добавляем число в список
        ws_list.append(i)
        try:
            with await condition:  # Захватываем condition
                condition.notify_all() # Уведомляем остальные таски
            i += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            break  # Задача отменена, выходим из цикла


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda n, f: shutdown())  # Обработчик Ctrl+C

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    condition = asyncio.Condition()

    # Главная задача ожидающая завершения сопрограмм producer и consumer
    main_task = asyncio.wait([producer(condition), consumer(condition)])
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # Даём возможность главной задаче завершится
        # после Ctrl+C
        loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
```

Comment: Мой косяк, что я не пояснил, что такое ws_list. Этот список веб-сокетов пополняется и убывает в другом месте, а в нашем коде он только проверяться должен.

Comment: Да без проблем, лишь бы в том коде вызывалось `condition.notify_all()`. Собственно, в данном примере сопрограмма `producer` выступает в роли вашего кода принимающего websocket-соединения, а `consumer` проверяющего.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы приостанавливать и снова запускать цикл из другого места кода, [можно `asyncio.Event()` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import itertools
import sys


async def restartable_loop(running):
    for char in itertools.cycle(r'/|\-'):  # heartbeat
        print('\b' + char, flush=True, end='', file=sys.stderr)
        if not running.is_set():
            await running.wait()  # pause the loop until restarted
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(.3)


async def driver(running):
    while True:
        running.set()  # start the loop
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        running.clear()  # pause the restartable loop
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


running = asyncio.Event()
asyncio.ensure_future(driver(running))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(restartable_loop(running))
```

Чтобы координировать две (и более) задачи: одна  — потребитель, другая — производитель, [можно `asyncio.Queue()` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#queue):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import itertools
import sys


async def producer(queue):
    for char in itertools.cycle(r'/|\-'):
        await queue.put(char)
        await asyncio.sleep(.3)


async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        char = await queue.get()
        print('\b' + char, flush=True, end='', file=sys.stderr)


queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=1)
asyncio.ensure_future(producer(queue))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(consumer(queue))
```

`.get()` будет ждать пока в очереди что-то появится. `.put()` будет ждать пока свободное место в очереди не появится.